# Is it possible to access NSURLCache in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, nsurlcache

I want to create a custom web view and proxy HTTP calls ([This blog explains what I'm trying to do](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html)).

I have an implementation working in Objective C using NSURLCache but I can't find a way to replace the NSURLCache from within MonoTouch. Is it possible? Or is there another way to achieve this?

In the Objective C implementation the replace the NSURLCache with your custom one in the AppDelegate here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    LocalSubstitutionCache *cache = [[LocalSubstitutionCache alloc] init];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could show the Objective-C code and the (partial) C# code so we can see where your *replace* issue is.

Comment: Apologies, updated with Objective C example of where NSURLCache is replaced. No useful C# code to show unfortunately

Comment: Ah, think I've found it: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlCache.SharedCache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

If you can do it from Objective-C then you should be able to do the same from C# using MonoTouch. Otherwise it's a bug and we'll work to fix it asap :-)

> but I can't find a way to replace the NSURLCache from within MonoTouch

If by replace you mean calling this (in Objective-C)

```
 +[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:]
```

then the MonoTouch equivalent is:

```
 NSUrlCache.SharedCache = ...;
```